# layout_generate_blocks_after observer is not redirecting to checkout/cart page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, redirect-url

I'm using the observer **layout_generate_blocks_after** to perform redirection to an empty cart on a condition but it is not redirecting. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the piece of code which i try to do:

```
$cart->truncate();
$cart->save();

$redirectUrl = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('checkout/cart'); 

$this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectUrl)->sendResponse();
die();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event 'layout_generate_blocks_after' will not fire on full page cache pages. It's only generated during the initial page render on a non-cache page.

Comment: I'm getting "too many redirects" error in "network" tab.

Comment: If it's a non-cached page this event will fire, redirect the user and then run again, and so redirect the user again, causing an infinite loop until the browser stops redirecting.